# Creating New Stage in Flash

Tags: flash, stage

Ok so I've been following a couple of tutorials on flash game development. A few of them mention creating a new stage instead of the default one but don't go into detail about them or how to create them.

An example from one of the tutorials.

"The Contents layer stores the mcGameStage where the flash game will take place. Notice that we're using this separate MovieClip called mcGameStage to let all the action take place. In a way, you'll see the benefits later on where we need to scroll things, or remove the game elementas totally. It will work better than if you were to load everything onto the stage itself."

I'm not exactly sure whats going on here and would appreciate a little clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial is suggesting that you add the contents of your game into your mcGameStage instance.

You always have the main Stage in the application by default, and then you add your mcGameStage to the main stage, which will be a container that will hold all of your game's display objects. Then you add any visual elements to the mcGameStage. The tutorial is saying that it would be much easier to manipulate them if you were to add them all to the mcGameStage container.

Other than that, you can never actually create another "Stage" than the default one, the stage is unique and cannot be manipulated that way.

If you were to use a main document class, this is actually what happens. Your main class is a child of the stage.

One way to get started, you can create a basic `Sprite` or `MovieClip` object. A sprite is a very basic container you can use for your basic needs including layering and interaction. The difference between Sprite and MovieClip is that Sprite does not have a timeline.

`var gameContainer:Sprite = new Sprite()`
`stage.addChild(gameContainer:Sprite)`

Then you can add any of your game elements to your gameContainer.

However, I don't want you to get confused. There's nothing inherently wrong with working directly on the stage at this point in learning. The problems arise when you're trying to dynamically load this .swfs into your application.

Another way to do this is just to use your flash file's Document Class. Assuming you're using the Flash IDE, just make a custom document class in the properties panel and work on that. That class gets added to the stage automagically. Click the pencil icon next to the Class: field, choose a name for your document class (we'll call it game), and create it.

You'll end up with something that looks like this:

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class Game extends MovieClip {
        public function Game() {
            //Things happen
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying and for answering both my other question as well!